# Matplotlib and pandas error when adding to plot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Edit: Added data for reference.

I'm using jupyter labs and trying to add some plots to an existing plot. I'm not understanding why I'm getting an error here or why catching the exceptions results in output that looks correct...

```
ax = dataframe[columns].plot(title=title, ax=ax)
if(not guide_columns == None):
    dataframe[guide_columns].plot(linestyle="--", ax=ax)
```

It runs and I get a long error (bottom). But the plot still happens and looks right. So I add a try/except to it....

```
ax = dataframe[columns].plot(title=title, ax=ax)
if(not guide_columns == None):
   try:
      dataframe[guide_columns].plot(linestyle="--", ax=ax)
   except KeyError:
      pass
```

And everything seems happy, but it seems wrong. I think maybe it has something to with the way pandas generates subsets of the dataframe?

### Data

```
dataframe["+20% Rate"] = rate_avg * 1.2
dataframe["-20% Rate"] = rate_avg * 0.8
columns = ["Rate (uCi/m^3)", 'Temp (C)', 'Pressure (kPa)',
               'Airflow (L/min)', 'DC (V)', 'Battery (V)']
guide_columns = ["+20% Rate", "-20% Rate"]

print(dataframe.head())
                           ts        id      sn  Rate (uCi/m^3)  Temp (C)  \
Test Time                                                                   
0.0       2018-08-13 16:01:57  43367947  336434         257.868      21.3   
2.0       2018-08-13 16:01:59  43367948  336434         268.182      21.3   
4.0       2018-08-13 16:02:01  43367949  336434         261.251      21.3   
6.0       2018-08-13 16:02:03  43367950  336434         261.251      21.3   
8.0       2018-08-13 16:02:05  43367951  336434         249.005      21.3   

           Pressure (kPa)  Airflow (L/min)  DC (V)  Battery (V)   +20% Rate \
Test Time                                                                     
0.0                    95              1.6    12.0         11.1  281.312188   
2.0                    95              1.7    12.0         11.1  281.312188   
4.0                    94              1.8    12.0         11.1  281.312188   
6.0                    94              1.8    12.0         11.1  281.312188   
8.0                    94              1.9    11.9         11.0  281.312188   

            -20% Rate  
Test Time              
0.0        187.541459  
2.0        187.541459  
4.0        187.541459  
6.0        187.541459  
8.0        187.541459
```

### Error (even though it plots....):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-591dc1863d4e> in <module>()
     20         status_log ("Processing " + file)
     21         dat = load_data(source_folder + file)
---> 22         analyse(dat, out_folder)
     23 
     24         #Get stop time

<ipython-input-22-7f43f1fe67f2> in analyse(dat, output_folder)
     36 
     37         #Do user plots
---> 38         process_each_sn(sn_records, t_sn, output_folder)
     39 
     40         #Gen statistics on data

<ipython-input-24-4359c5fd8837> in process_each_sn(sn_records, sn, 
output_folder)
     27     #Plot Average per time
     28     #Do 1hr Avg
---> 29     m3100_plot_avg_of_hours(sn_records, sn, 1, output_folder, 
y_axis_log=True)
     30     #Do 8hr Avg
     31     m3100_plot_avg_of_hours(sn_records, sn, 8, output_folder, 
y_axis_log=True)

<ipython-input-20-306b064316e1> in m3100_plot_avg_of_hours(dataframe, sn, 
hr_avg_time, out_folder, y_axis_log)
    108     #Plot avg data for these columns
    109     columns = ["Rate (uCi/m^3)", 'Temp (C)', 'Pressure (kPa)', 
'Airflow (L/min)', 'DC (V)', 'Battery (V)']
--> 110     m3100_plot_single_sn(avg_data, sn, columns, title, out_folder, 
y_axis_log)
    111 
    112     #Convert time stamp to hours for table

<ipython-input-20-306b064316e1> in m3100_plot_single_sn(dataframe, sn, 
columns, title, out_folder, guide_columns, y_axis_log, fig_size)
     55     ax = dataframe[columns].plot(title="SN: " + str(sn) + " - " + 
title, ax=ax)
     56     if(not guide_columns == None):
---> 57         dataframe[guide_columns].plot(linestyle="--", ax=ax)
     58         #try:
     59             #dataframe.loc[:,guide_columns].plot(linestyle="--", 
ax=ax)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
__getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
_getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
_get_item_cache(self, item)
   2487         res = cache.get(item)
   2488         if res is None:
-> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
   2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2491             cache[item] = res

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, 
item, fastpath)
   4113 
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items)) 
[isna(self.items)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081 
   3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: True
```

Comment: what's the value of guide_columns?

Comment: Added data.....

Comment: Maybe not the root cause of your exception, but  `if guide_columns  is not None` is the preferred way of saying `if not guide_columns == None`. Also no parenthesis in python :)

Comment: Yeah I know, I bounce between this and embedded C/C++ a lot.